# How to get the fractional part of a number in apex

Tags: apex, decimal

I need to get the number after de decimal point.  For example I have:

344.567

And I need to get in a variable 567.

I've tried the next:

```
decimal d=43.3432332343344;

String s = String.valueOf(aa);

String[] arrayDecimal = s.split('.');
```

But the result is an empty array. How can I do this? Is there any way to get this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the other answer, you can also use [`String.subStringAfter`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) here as below (there could still be other ways to manipulate the string).

```
Decimal d = 43.3432332343344;
String s = String.valueOf(d); // assuming you meant to use d here
String afterDecimal = s.substringAfter('.');
```

Comment: Thanks. it is exactly what I wanted is easier than I was doing.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to use String conversion at all to obtain the fractional part of a `Decimal`.

```
Decimal d = 5.6;

System.debug(d - d.round(System.RoundingMode.DOWN));
```

> 0.6

```
Decimal d = -5.6;

System.debug(d - d.round(System.RoundingMode.DOWN));
```

> -0.6

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but what I wanted is no to get 0.6. I need to asign in a variable: 6. If the number is 560.006 I would like to store 006.

Answer (score 5):

String#split wants a Regular Expression. "." matches "any character." You'll need to "escape" the "." to have it work as you expect:

```
decimal d=43.3432332343344;
String s = String.valueOf(d);
String[] arrayDecimal = s.split('\\.');
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

```
Math.abs(d - d.intValue());
```

> d = -7.81 returns 0.81

```
d - d.intValue();
```

> d = -7.81 returns -0.81

But if you just want the string `81` - the fractional digits, then @sfdcfox answer is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but yes, I need to get the String 81 not 0.81.

Comment: @alejandro - be sure to accept sfdcfox's answer pls